# Nodejs extract post data and display it in HTML forms

Tags: node.js, html

I need to get the value from post data and which should be displayed in the HTML using nodejs, in php we will do like following

```
<p><?php echo $_POST['data']; ?></p>
```

how we can do the same in nodejs? Is it possible to do with out using jade? if not how we can do this using jade

Answer (score 1):

Use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) with [EmbeddedJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)

Here's an example using ExpressJS + EmbeddedJS

```
//Setting up things for POST Param parsing with a limit to 15mb POST data.
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '15mb'})); // to support JSON bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit:'15mb' })); // to support URL-encoded bodies

app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.render('test.ejs', {post_data: req.body});
});

//Now in the EJS file you set :
<p><%= post_data.data %></p>
```

Comment: is it possible to do with out any template engine?

Comment: You can always create an API in nodejs to get the informations you want and update this informations using javascript in client side if you really don't want to use template engines.

Comment: I have up voted your answer, if I am understand your view clearly the answer would be like I have to make a call to nodejs using socketio and from there I have to update the data to html is it?

Comment: Not necessarily from socket.io, you can create a RESTful API aswell, but yes, the only way i can think of (i'm not saying theres no other way, i'm saying i'm not aware of other) changing html information without using template engines is doing a request and updating the informations in client side.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, i assume you are making a call like this,

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "domain.com/post/url", 
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({formField : $("#formfield").val()}),
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
    },
    error: function(xhrObj){
    }})
```

Then in the backend, when you are rendering the view with jade, do this

```
app.use( bodyParser.json() )
api.post("/post/url", function(req, res, next){
  res.render("iamaview", {"iamavar": req.body.formField})
})
```

where `app` is an expressJs app and `api` is an express router

And in app/views/iamaview.jade, use `iamavar` as a variable,

```
#{iamavar}
```